# Call Func<> with argument of type object

Tags: c#, expression-trees, func

I have (for instance) a `Func<int, int>` which I want to call as usual, except that the parameter is of type `object` rater than `int`. I only know the exact type of the Func and the argument at runtime, because the Func was created using Expression trees and is now accessed from a `dynamic` variable. (Simplified) code example:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace FuncExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object myFunc = CreateFunc(); // Could return something like
                                          // Func<int, int>, but may return a
                                          // completely different Func<> depending on
                                          // arguments etc.
            object result = getFromFunc(5, myFunc);
        }

        public static object CreateFunc()
        {
            LambdaExpression expr = Expression.Lambda(
                /*
                 * Create an expression
                 */
                );
            return expr.Compile();
        }

        public static object getFromFunc(object arg, object func)
        {
            dynamic dynFunc = func;
            return dynFunc(arg); // <------- Throws exception
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make the code convert `arg` into an integer or whatever Type the argument is? I tried making a generic method that casts the object to a certain type and then invoking it through reflection like this:

```
public static T asT<T>(object n)
{
    return (T)n;
}
```

for `getFromFunc`:

```
MethodInfo con = typeof(Program).GetMethod("asT").MakeGenericMethod(func.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]);
return dfunc(con.Invoke(null, new[] { value }));
```

But `MethodInfo.Invoke` also returns `object`.
Any ideas on how to make sure the argument has the correct type?

Comment: what exception does it throw?

Comment: @CharlesLambert On my system, I get "Delegate 'System.Func<int,int>' has some invalid arguments". It uses `arg`'s static type, `object`, which is inappropriate for a function with a parameter of type `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already using `dynamic`, so why not use `dynamic`?

```
return dynFunc((dynamic)arg);
```

This makes sure `arg`'s runtime type gets used for determining whether it's an appropriate argument.

Comment: Is `if (!(func.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == arg.GetType()))` a valid way to check if its the wrong type?

Comment: @MarkusHimmel That would throw an exception if `arg` is `null`, and would not perform any implicit conversions so would cause a false negative if, for example, the function takes an interface or base class and the argument is a derived class. I think you're better off not checking beforehand: you can reliably catch the exception and do something meaningful if the runtime detects that the argument has the wrong type.

Answer (score 5):

All delegates derive from System.Delegate.  You can use the System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke method to call a delegate whose type you don't know at compile time, similar to calling a method using MethodInfo.Invoke().  For example:

```
class Program
{
    public static Delegate CreateFunc()
    {
      return new Func<int, int>(x => x + 1);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var func = CreateFunc();
        object inArg = 42;
        object result = func.DynamicInvoke(inArg);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    // this could be any other lambda expression
    Func<object, object> unknownFunc = (a) => { return 13; };

    int result = (int) unknownFunc(13);
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I don't know at compile-time wether it will be an `int` or any other type.